# Cannot find symbole - class file

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm creating a class that implements `DirectoryStream` so I can iterate through a directory. However, I am not able to get beyond compile time errors because, when I try to import "java.nio.file", it states "cannot find symbol - class file". Does anyone have a clue why?

```
    import java.nio.file;
                   ^ to ^ is highlighted red when I compile the file.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

`java.nio.file` is a [package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) not a class

Comment: I tried that, but it then states: "package java.nio.file does not exist" what does this mean?

Comment: what is your java version ??

Comment: are you using Eclipse? in that case assure that you are using right compiler for you project.

Comment: I'm currently using Bluej because eclipse required a library and I had no idea which one to select.

Comment: It's not related to your question, but I suggest you to move to wider accepted IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. You can get more help from other users. To grab the idea: BlueJ tagged question on SO: 530, Eclipse: 37932.

Comment: okay thank you for the advice, i just switched to Eclipse, how do i change my compiler to Java 7?

Comment: In true spirit of StackOverflow, i think that first of all, you should accept an answer as the right one. Independently of IDE you are using, your import statement has to be corrected as one of the answers suggests (assuming you are on JDK7). About Eclipse question, well this is another SO question that deserves its own autonomy, ie, just post a new question and you will find many users willing to answer (me included). Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
import java.nio.file;
```

tries to import the class named `file` from the package `java.nio`. Which obviously doesn't exist (in the JRE).

In you code, the statement should be

```
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
```

(and double check that you're using Java 7, it's not available in previous versions)